# Extract last lines of a logfile by time

Tags: command-line, logs, timestamps, tail

```
tail -n 100 myfile.log
```

gives my the last 100 lines of myfile.log.

Is there an existing tool that expects the first "column" of each line in a file as a timestamp and can give me the n last hours/days/...?

We can assume the lines in the file have ascending timestamps.

e.g.

```
tailtm -h 10 myfile.log
```

The tool should accept most common timestamp-formats of Linux logfiles.

Comment: Is sorting (from the title) important?

Comment: stdout of systemd services is redirected to journald. If it's your case you can just use `journalctl -u abc.service --since=XXX`

Comment: This is a nice way! But can I use it to find PAM-entries too?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments it is working with journalctl.

**EDIT**

```
journalctl -u sshd.service --since "2019-11-01 12:00:00"
```

I generate the sinde-timestamp for each call so I can have the timerange back as I need.

Thanks to mrc02_kr!

Comment: Please [edit] this so it looks like an answer to the question.  It’s OK to repeat information provided by somebody else if you give credit to the original author.